# Проблема с чтением с биржи Bittrex.com

Tags: php, api

Хочу прочитать с биржи через ее API котировки, не получается, выдает NULL.
хостинг jino.ru, curl на хостинге включен.
Что делать чтобы заработало?
заранее спасибо.

```
$apikey = 'xxx';
$apisecret = 'xxxy';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets';
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
var_dump($obj);
```

пробовал проекты с github - тоже безрезультатно. вообще в exception уходят.
Хостинг ответил что bittrex.com не блокировал. Жду ответа техподдержки bittrex.

Comment: В `$execResult ` у вас что? Булевая переменная? Сделайте ей var_dump

Comment: $execResult = false

Comment: в браузерах запрос 
https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets обрабатывается нормально и выводятся результаты.

Comment: Свяжитесь с техподдержкой, на хостинге бывает запрещают обращение CURL к внешним сайтам (как у hostinger.ru, например). Также проверьте объяснение ошибки через curl_error.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov - curl_error = Failed to connect to bittrex.com port 443: Время ожидания соединения истекло

Comment: В консоли сервера хост пингуется? `nmap bittrex.com -p443`

Comment: @vp_arth с консолью не работал. все через веб-интерфейс. https://poloniex.com читается, или хостинг заблокировал bittrex или последний заблокировал хостинг ?

Comment: Попробуйте curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); При заходе на HTTP делается редирект на HTTPS, вероятно там делается какое-то перенаправление. (Из http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Результат]

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/KielD-01/Bittrex-Reader/tree/master)

Если Вам будут нужны дополнительные поля - спрашивайте. Помогу.

Comment: спасибо, только я не представляю как использовать ваш проект

Comment: @SergSergeev, Вы с Git'ом знакомы?

Comment: на 1-5% наверно

Comment: @SergSergeev, скайчайте проект с помощью SourceTree/SmartGit. Установите зависимости с помощью composer и запустите проект через консоль

Comment: я планирую дальнейшую обработку. чем поможет ваша консоль ?

Comment: Если Вы захотите это все сделать на клиентской части - то сделаю перенос функционала на контроллеры.

Comment: Вы хотели, чтобы работало. Я предоставил Вам вариант решения задачи полностью. Не было укзано, что нужно вывод на клиент, а не в консоль или файл. Или же отправка на телеграм.

Comment: cпасибо, но ваш вариант сложноват для меня.

Comment: Давайте я вам позже помогу. Напишите мне на почту romanko95.rk@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

curl_exec возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. Однако, если установлена опция CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, при успешном завершении будет возвращен результат, а при неудаче - FALSE.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: не помогло, false

Answer (score 0):

В соответсвии с документацией не нужно подписывать этот запрос - https://bittrex.com/Home/API - это публичный АПИ.

А возвращает FALSE потому что обращаетесь к HTTPS без проверки сертификата. Или выключайте его через

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Или устанавливайте его на своё хранилище, где может быть сделана проверка:

```
curl_setopt($config,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($config,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
curl_setopt($config,CURLOPT_CAINFO,'ca-bundle.crt');
curl_setopt($config,CURLOPT_CAPATH,'ca-bundle.crt');
```

Правка - только что проверял на локальной машине этот код, все работает, у вас вероятно нет доступа к CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: проверку отключил. не помогло.